# Encoding issue with curly brackets and space in UriBuilder

Tags: java, encoding, jersey, uribuilder

I am using the `com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl` implementation of `UriBuilder` to encode a URL (version 1.19). The issue arises when the query parameter of my URL includes both curly brackets and a space.

Example:

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = fromUri("www.something.com")
        .queryParam("q", "{some thing}");

return uriBuilder.build().toString();
```

This fails with:

```
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilderException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 27: www.something.com?q=%7Bsome thing%7D
```

Which is interesting, as if I take the curly brackets away, I get the expected encoding: `www.something.com?q=some+thing`...

`org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder` encodes that as I would expect, which is: `www.something.com?q=%7Bsome+thing%7D`

I've tried doing this:

```
...
.queryParam("q", UriComponent.encode(searchQuery, UriComponent.Type.QUERY_PARAM)).
.build();
```

But then the space character also gets encoded to `www.something.com?q=%7Bsome%2Bthing%7D`.

What do I have to do to get `www.something.com?q=%7Bsome+thing%7D`?

Comment: Where is `fromUri` from?

Comment: It's from `jsr311-api-1.1.1: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`

Comment: `build` returns a `URI` instance, not  `UriBuilder `

Comment: sorry, that was me adding build after I copy-pasted the code here. I'll edit.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using jersey-client v1.9.1 and your code run with no error.

Here is my maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And the java code:

```
import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            URI url = UriBuilder.fromUri("www.something.com")
                    .queryParam("q", "{some thing}")
                    .build();
            System.out.println(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output: `www.something.com?q=%7Bsome+thing%7D`

**UPDATE**

The curly braces are the reason for failing with v1.19 (see [the documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/uris-and-links.html))

Here is a working version for v1.19:

```
        URI url = UriBuilder.fromPath("www.something.com")
                .queryParam("q", "{value}")
                .build("{some thing}", "value");
        System.out.println(url);
```

Comment: @pavlos163 Yes, the space seems to be the problem.

Comment: That works. It's a bit weird, and I wonder if they've fixed in in newer version of Jersey... But yeah for now that's what I'll do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: 
You need two library
**jersey-core-1.19.2** and **javax.ws.rs** and **jersey-client-1.19.2**

```
public class ClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String queryString =  URLEncoder.encode("{some thing}", "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(queryString);
        URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("www.something.com")
                .queryParam("q", queryString)
                .build();
        String url = uri.toString().replace("%2B", "+");
        System.out.println(url);
    }
}
```